# How to define Imageview in getter setter method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-handler

Hello guy i am new to Kotlin android and working on a demo in this demo i am trying to get an image from the gallery and set it in my recyclerview but i am getting the solution requesting you to please find me a solution Thanks in Advance!!

This is my CustomAdapter.kt:-

```
package com.example.itemgetset

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.PopupMenu
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar

@Suppress("UNREACHABLE_CODE")
class CustomAdapter(
    private var activity: Activity,
    private val userList: ArrayList<ProductInfoGetSet>,
    private var isforlist: Boolean,
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemview=
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemview)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val productInfoGetSet: ProductInfoGetSet = userList[position]

        holder.image = productInfoGetSet.image
        holder.txtId.text = productInfoGetSet.id
        holder.txtName.text = productInfoGetSet.name
        holder.txtQuantity.text = productInfoGetSet.quantity
        holder.txtPrice.text = productInfoGetSet.price

        val id = userList[position].id
        Log.e(TAG, "List item ID: $id")

        holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener {

            val popup = PopupMenu(activity, holder.buttonViewOption)
            popup.inflate(R.menu.pop_menu)
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
                when (item.itemId) {
                    R.id.edit -> {
                        val intent = Intent(activity, AddDetails::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("isFor", "Update")
                        intent.putExtra("id", productInfoGetSet.id)
                        intent.putExtra("image",productInfoGetSet.image)
                        intent.putExtra("name", productInfoGetSet.name)
                        intent.putExtra("quantity", productInfoGetSet.quantity)
                        intent.putExtra("price", productInfoGetSet.price)
                        activity.startActivity(intent)
                    }
                    R.id.delete -> {
                        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                        builder.setTitle("Delete")
                        builder.setMessage("Do you want to delete the item?")

                        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
                            userList.removeAt(position)
                            notifyItemRemoved(position)
                            val snack = Snackbar
                                .make(
                                    holder.linearly,
                                    "Item was removed from the list.",
                                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                                )
                            snack.show()
                        }
                        builder.setNegativeButton("No") { _, _ ->
                        }
                        val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
                        dialog.show()
                    }
                }
                false
            }
            popup.show()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name) as TextView
        val txtId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_id) as TextView
        var image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2) as ImageView
        val txtQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_quantity) as TextView
        val txtPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price) as TextView
        val linearly: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout)
        val buttonViewOption = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.txt_Options) as TextView
    }
}
```

in this adapter i gent and error on holder.image = productInfoGetSet.image this line and not get solved.

This is my AddDeatils.kt:-

```
package com.example.itemgetset

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Message
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.add_item.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.list_layout.*

class AddDetails : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var btnSubmit: Button
    private lateinit var edtName: EditText
    private lateinit var edtQuantity: EditText
    private lateinit var edtPrice: EditText
    private lateinit var imageview: ImageView

    companion object {
        private const val IMAGE_PICK_CODE = 1000
        private const val PERMISSION_CODE = 1001
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "ResourceType")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.add_item)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        findViewById()
        onclick()

        if (intent.getStringExtra("isFor").equals("Update")) {
            intent.getStringExtra("image")?.toInt()?.let { imageview.setImageResource(it) }
            edtName.setText(intent.getStringExtra("name"))
            edtQuantity.setText(intent.getStringExtra("quantity"))
            edtPrice.setText(intent.getStringExtra("price"))
        }
    }

    private fun findViewById() {
        btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit)
        edtName = findViewById(R.id.edt_name)
        edtQuantity = findViewById(R.id.edt_quantity)
        edtPrice = findViewById(R.id.edt_price)
        imageview = findViewById(R.id.image_view)
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    private fun onclick() {

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener {
            when {
                edtName.text.trim().isEmpty() -> {
                    edtName.error = "Please Enter Product Name"
                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "Please Enter Product Name",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                        .show()
                }
                edtQuantity.text.trim().isEmpty() -> {
                    edtQuantity.error = "Please Enter Product Quantity"
                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "Please Enter Product Quantity",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
                edtPrice.text.trim().isEmpty() -> {
                    edtPrice.error = "Please Enter Product Price"
                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "Please Enter Product Price",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                        .show()
                }
                else -> {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "Product Added Successfully ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()

                    val temp = Temp()
                    temp.image = imageview.toString()
                    temp.name = edtName.text.toString()
                    temp.quantity = edtQuantity.text.toString()
                    temp.price = edtPrice.text.toString()

                    if (intent.getStringExtra("isFor").equals("Update")) {
                        temp.id = intent.getStringExtra("id").toString()
                    }

                    val message: Message = Message.obtain()
                    message.what = 111
                    message.obj = temp
                    MainActivity.handler.sendMessage(message)
                    finish()
                }
            }
        }
        imageview.setOnClickListener {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
                ) {
                    val permissions = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_CODE)
                } else {
                    pickImageFromGallery()
                }
            } else {
                pickImageFromGallery()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSION_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    pickImageFromGallery()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }

    private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE) {
            imageview.setImageURI(data?.data)

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my MainActivity.kt:-

```
package com.example.itemgetset

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Message
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.GridView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.ListView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var activity: Activity
    val userList = ArrayList<ProductInfoGetSet>()
    private lateinit var btnProductAdd: Button
    lateinit var llEmptyView: LinearLayout
    lateinit var llMain: LinearLayout
    private var listView: ListView? = null
    private var gridView: GridView? = null
    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var llFab: LinearLayout
    private lateinit var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
    private lateinit var gridLayoutManager: GridLayoutManager
    private lateinit var adapter: CustomAdapter
    private var isforlist = true

    companion object {
        var handler: Handler = Handler()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        activity = this
        initView()
        onClicks()
        setUpData()

        handler = @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
        object : Handler() {
            override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
                if (msg.what == 111) {
                    val temp: Temp = msg.obj as Temp

                    if (temp.id == "") {
                        userList.add(
                            ProductInfoGetSet(
                                (userList.size + 1).toString(),
                                temp.image,
                                temp.name,
                                temp.quantity,
                                temp.price,
                            )
                        )
                        adapter = CustomAdapter(activity, userList, isforlist)
                        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                    } else {
                        for (i in userList.indices) {
                            if (userList[i].id == temp.id) {
                                userList[i].id = temp.id
                                userList[i].image = temp.image
                                userList[i].name = temp.name
                                userList[i].quantity = temp.quantity
                                userList[i].price = temp.price
                            }
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
                if (userList.size > 0) {
                    llEmptyView.visibility = View.GONE
                    llMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    llEmptyView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    llMain.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun changeLayoutManager() {
        if (recyclerView.layoutManager == linearLayoutManager) {
            recyclerView.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
        } else {
            recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        }
    }

    private fun initView() {
        btnProductAdd = findViewById(R.id.btn_product_add)
        llFab = findViewById(R.id.ll_fab)
        llEmptyView = findViewById(R.id.llEmptyView)
        listView = findViewById(R.id.list_product)
        gridView = findViewById(R.id.list_productGV)
        llMain = findViewById(R.id.llMain)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
    }

    private fun onClicks() {
        btnProductAdd.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, AddDetails::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("isFor", "Add")
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        llFab.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, AddDetails::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("isFor", "Add")
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    private fun setUpData() {
        if (userList.size > 0) {
            llEmptyView.visibility = View.GONE
            llMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            llEmptyView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            llMain.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.menu_view) {
            if (userList.size > 0) {
                changeLayoutManager()
            }
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

My ProductInfoGetSet.kt:-

```
package com.example.itemgetset

import android.widget.ImageView

class ProductInfoGetSet(
    var id: String,
    var image: ImageView,
    var name: String,
    var quantity: String,
    var price: String
)
```

Temp.kt:-

```
package com.example.itemgetset

import android.widget.ImageView

class Temp {
    var id: String = ""
    var image: ImageView =
    var name: String = ""
    var quantity: String = ""
    var price: String = ""
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: "holder.image" is ImageView and "productInfoGetSet.image" is image URL(I think String) so maybe it is cause issue, can you set the by calling some ImageView methods to set the image like holder.image.setImageURI(imageUrl here).

Comment: I try it in my Temp.kt file i'll also change it but i don't know how to define imageview i define textview as 'var name: String = ""' Can you please help in this

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are new to Android. I will list down points below for you to understand clearly.

1. As a standard practice you must not use ImageView in any model as Model can only hold data.
2. Use databinding for views.
3. As suggested by Rupam Saini, you can use Glide or Picasso for image loading.
4. You can't pass imageView in bundle as it will create different object when you read it again. There is a chance of leaking context also.

Regarding your question

> in this adapter i gent and error on holder.image = productInfoGetSet.image this line and not get solved.

You are trying to set an ImageView to another ImageView which is not correct. Temp file is incorrect, there is no value after = . So Temp file must also have error.

Comment: Yes there now only on error that I have to define some thing in ImageView=  but the problem is that i don't know how to define it can you please help me in this.

Comment: The approach of having ImageView in model is not correct as I mentioned in point 1 and 4. You should switch to databinding or set a url in Model and load it in ImageView at runTime.

Comment: temp.image = imageview.toString() this is also wrong

Comment: I only have problem right now is this that how can i set image in getter setter. can anyone please help in this.

Comment: @Jay3421 - You cannot set image using getter setter. You can have the url and set it using the setImageUri method on the Imageview or you can have the Drawable Resource Id and you can set it using setImageResource on the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be better if you show your ProductInfoGetSet class and the error logs.

You should not set the image directly

```
holder.image = productInfoGetSet.image
```

Instead you can get the image's URI and then set it like this

```
holder.image.setImageUri(imageUri)
```

If you are still getting issues then you can use the [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: I try this but now i have to define image in temp.kt and there i get an error i don't know how to define ImageView there Please help me in this. Thanks in Advance. And i also edited and put that file please take a look.

Comment: The problem seems to be in `temp.image = imageview.toString()`

Comment: That i also change it. but now to problem is in define the ImageView in Temp.kt file.

Comment: You can't get the path or URI by doing that. Instead you should change the data type of image in both the ProductInfoGetSet and Temp. Also change the imageView's data type to URI in AddDetails.kt and initialise it with the URI in onActivityResult. At last, change the line  `holder.image = productInfoGetSet.image` to `holder.image.setImageUri(productInfoGetSet.image)` in CustomAdapter.

Comment: I only have problem right now is this that how can i set image in getter setter. can anyone please help in this.